# Is it possible to do "mixed" word-diff in git?

Tags: git

I'd really like to have something like the following:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/file b/file
index a7d45cf..4155b93 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
-The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
+The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
+The quick red fox jumps over the hazy frog.


$ git diff --word-diff
diff --git a/file b/file
index a7d45cf..4155b93 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
The quick brown fox [-jumps-]{+jumped+} over the lazy dog.
The quick [-brown-]{+red+} fox jumps over the [-lazy dog.-]{+hazy frog.+}


$ git diff --word-diff --unimplemented-flag
diff --git a/file b/file
index a7d45cf..4155b93 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
The quick brown fox [-jumps-]{+jumped+} over the lazy dog.
-The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
+The quick red fox jumps over the hazy frog.
```

In this case, the basic idea is to be able to set a threshold and if more than N word-diffs appear on a line, the line is presented without the word-diff, but instead as a full line.  Does some similar functionality already exist?

Comment: eg `git diff --word-diff=mixed --word-diff-threshold=2`

Comment: Note that `--word-diff` really does a line by line diff and then post-processes it. That's built in to Git, while the diff-highlight is still only sort of loosely coupled to Git (though it's provided *with* Git now, rather than just being an external package). You could write your own post-processor to do the same sort of thing in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any such option, but an alternative is [diff-highlight](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight), which achieves essentially the same goal: you get a full diff (i.e. without `--word-diff`), but the words that actually changed from a line to another. In your example, you'd get:

[image: diff-highlight screenshot]